# Create custom DNS name server in C

Tags: c, dns

Need to create a custom DNS name server using C which will check against a mysql db to see if the client IP need to be directed to a different server. Using this for a test network so requests to foo.com will only go there if true lookup is enabled, otherwise requests will be directed to a development env. Any suggestions/recommendations?

Currently looking at libevent with something like ldns or c-ares

Comment: Do you need this name server to be recursive or not?

Comment: Currently there is a perl dns name server in place using Stanford::DNSserver, this crashes and requires daily restarts so I am looking at writing similar functionality in C. Stanford::DNSserver as far as i know is only authoritative. The goal is to act like a dns server and modify only certain requests based on information in a mysql table and forward all other requests to a real dns server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with libevent 1.4 which contains its own functions for dealing with dns requests. The evdns functions that libevent contains are pretty straight forward and where exactly what i needed to create q custom dns server. I looked at using bind, but didnt want to deal with having to set up zones and extra configuration, evdns allowed me to use the existing resolv.conf to forward any dns requests to real name servers and to modify the responses as needed based on information contained in a mysql table.

Answer (score 2):

BIND already has a mySQL extension (using dynamic loadable zones). All you need to do is create a table of addresses with translations and define the queries that build the correct DNS records using the table.

For full documentation see: http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to something that I am working on right now, except in my case I have to make the DNS server return different error messages than normal to accommodate for the fact that it runs on a private network.

I decided to just download BIND source code and write my modifications as a patch to that. Then for deployment, we can download the latest BIND source, which will include new security patches, apply our customisation patch, and build it.

I recommend that you do much the same thing, just get BIND and modify it as needed. You can get BIND and all its documentation [here at ISC.ORG](https://www.isc.org/software/bind).

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea. BIND 9 (unlike what is planned for its successor BIND 10) is not really made for hackability.

Comment: That just means that it is not as easy to hack at BIND 9 because the source code is not as well organized and refactored. But sometimes developers just have to dig in and figure things out. In any case, the OP specified C and may be very skilled in its use, otherwise I would have suggested using Python and Twisted Names which comes with a DNS server for hacking.

Answer (score 1):

Bob, I've already written a mash-up of `ldns` and `libevent` which should provide you with a good start to be able to do exactly what you want.

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/evldns/