# Very simple DNS server

Tags: c, linux, perl, dns

I have a linux server has an ad-hoc wireless network for clients to connect to. Once connected I want users to always be redirected to it's own web server no matter what URL they type in. The large solution would be to set up a full DNS server (with BIND or equivalent) but that seems like overkill. All I need is a simple program that will listen for any DNS request and always respond with the same IP address.

I looked around for one but couldn't seem to find one. It would preferably be written in C or Perl as I don't really want to install any other scripting languages.

Comment: How about dnsmasq: http://serverfault.com/q/351108

Comment: You can use dnsmasq (DNS+DHCP simple)

Comment: FWIW, using DNS to catch clients on wireless APs is now considered bad practise because it interferes with the DNS cache. Decent captive portals now use HTTP interception instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Net::DNS::Nameserver](http://p3rl.org/Net::DNS::Nameserver) and write your own reply handler.

For C, look at:

- [How to Build a custom simple DNS server in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649618/how-to-build-a-custom-simple-dns-server-in-c-c)
- [Create custom DNS name server in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614243/create-custom-dns-name-server-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest using [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html). It's more full-featured than you absolutely need, but it's very well-written, small, and easy to install, and the only configuration you would need to give it is `--address='/#/1.2.3.4'` to tell it to answer all queries (that don't match some other rule) with the address 1.2.3.4. dnsmasq is well-known and maintained and probably a more robust server than Net::DNS::Nameserver.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [fakedns.py](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/491264/) when reversing malware.  It may be too limited for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

As I answered in the other related question, I wrote a basic DNS server in C++ for a job interview under BSD license.

I think the code was pretty clean, though I didn't made unit tests :-(
I tested it with dig, and it took about a week understanding DNS protocol + implementing + documentation.

If anyone would want to extend it, I guess it would not be very difficult.
Because I think it only supported inverse queries, as that was asked in the exercise.

The code could be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/dns-server/

It was migrated to: https://github.com/tomasorti/dns-server