# Intercepting data on DNS server

Tags: linux, dns, centos

I want to set up my own DNS server. That is, instead of using google's own public DNS servers `8.8.8.8`, I want to use mine; let's say at `195.33.65.97`. I want to set this up on a Cent OS server.

However, I want to add a middle layer on the server, whenever the request arrives to my DNS server, I will have control on the request. For example, if it is asking for `skype.com`, do not process the order.

Can this be done?

Comment: OK, and what do you want to do with requests other than skype.com?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the specific DNS server you are using. However, on Linux, the [bind9](https://wiki.debian.org/Bind9) server is the most common one. You can intercept / handle a domain using a `zone` configuration. For example:

```
 zone "skype.com" {
      type master​;
      file "/path/to/blocked_domains.dns";
 };
```

In the file "/path/to/blocked_domains.dns", you configure how to handle blocked domains (e.g. having it resolve to the address of a server in which you host an error page, for example).

See [How to block or sinkhole domains in BIND](https://community.jisc.ac.uk/library/janet-services-documentation/how-block-or-sinkhole-domains-bind) for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done. At the very least you could write your own DNS server (it's easier than it sounds)

See [Very simple DNS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037188/very-simple-dns-server)